# using modernizr to test for video tag

Tags: javascript, browser, modernizr

I was given an assignment where I have to use Modernizr to check if a browser is capable of running certain features. I have tested this code on Firefox, Safari and chrome. (I am up-to-date in all three browsers). My code for geolocation and localStorage works. However, I cannot get a video to display in my browser at all. I'm not trying to do much with the video other than load and display it on the page. I do get the alert though that says that video.js has loaded. I'm also getting two errors in my console "the character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it" and "HTTP content-type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVVmsxR67ZE failed." Any suggestions on how I can modify this or correct it so that the video loads?

```
<script src="Modernizr.js"></script>
   <script>
        Modernizr.load([
           "features.js",
           {
               test: Modernizr.geolocation,
               yep: "geolocation.js",
               nope: "noGeolocation.js"
               },
           {
               test: Modernizr.localstorage,
               yep: "localStorage.js",
               nope: "noLocalStorage.js"                             
             },
           {
               test: Modernizr.video,
               yep: "video.js",
               nope: "novideo.js",
               complete: function() {
                 init();
               }
             }            
          ]);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="id">
 </div>
 <ul id="features">
 </ul>
</body>

function showVideo() {
 var id = document.getElementById("id");
 var video = document.createElement("video");
 video.setAttribute("src", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBc7UWZ8-hg"); 
 id.appendChild(video);
 video.play();
 alert("video.js loaded");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 video.setAttribute("src", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBc7UWZ8-hg");
```

the src should point to an actual video file, it's no video file it is a html webpage.

try to make your page work properly before attempting to use modernizr

Comment: mpm has it ... ie, instead of using the URL of the page which includes the video plus other stuff, on the youtube page look little below the video for the share > embed link and grab the URL for just the video : http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZUAg51kA42M